# Dockerfile FROM Insecure Registry

Tags: docker, build, dockerfile, docker-registry

Is there a way to build a docker image from a Dockerfile that uses a base image from a local, insecure registry hosted in Gitlab. For example, if my Dockerfile were:

```
FROM insecure.registry.local:/mygroup/myproject/image:latest
```

When I run `docker build .` I get the following error:

```
failed to solve with frontend dockerfile.v0: failed to create LLB definition:.... http: server gave HTTP response to HTTPS client
```

When I've been interacting with our registry and received similar types http/https errors, I would alter the docker daemon configuration file to include:

```
   ...
   "insecure-registries" : ["insecure.registry.local"]
   ...
```

and everything would work when executing a particular docker command that would trigger it. I'm able to run `docker login insecure.registry.local` successfully. Is there a way either in the Dockerfile itself, through the `docker build` command or other alternative to have it pull the image successfully in the `FROM` statement from an insecure registry?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Depending on your version, you may need to include the scheme in the insecure registry definition. Newer versions of buildkit should not have this issue, so an upgrade may also help.

```
   ...
   "insecure-registries" : [
     "insecure.registry.local",
     "http://insecure.registry.local"
   ]
   ...
```

Comment: This seemed to do the trick for me! I would have never guessed to try such a thing, I do appreciate the help! What command should I run to check the version and what version would you expect I wouldn't need to do this with?

Comment: @fowlball1010 `docker version` and `docker info` will tell you about your docker engine. I'm not sure what release has this fix, but a documentation update was rejected because a commit was made to make it irrelevant. That commit was made July 2020, so at the very least anything before then will have the old behavior. I just don't know when that commit would have been included in the docker engine itself. https://github.com/docker/docker.github.io/pull/11023

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately there is not that much information about the actual error.

So here are a couple of things that may fix the issue you described:

- Ensure your file is called `Dockerfile` (only the `D` is supposed to be capitalized)
- Reload and restart the docker daemon after your changes (`sudo systemctl daemon-reload && sudo systemctl restart docker`)
- Don't use the docker buildkit (`export DOCKER_BUILDKIT=0 && export COMPOSE_DOCKER_CLI_BUILD=0 && docker build .`

Comment: Disabling buildkit did it for me.