# Docker Insecure Registry Problem when `docker build' pulls base image

Tags: docker, docker-registry

When using `docker build`, pulling the base image from a private registry fails with
`http: server gave HTTP response to HTTPS client`

It should not a problem of setting `insecure-registries` however, because

1. `insecure-registries` is set
2. docker pull and push are working without problems

I can workaround it by pulling the base image first and then calling `docker build`, but I would prefer to get to the root of the problem.

The problem occurred on Mac as well as Windows.

Any idea what might be the problem?

Edit: The solution of [Dockerfile FROM Insecure Registry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68596864/dockerfile-from-insecure-registry) doesn't work for me.
For my insecure-registries entry I use ip:port. When I try to enter http://ip:port I get an error message:

```
Error invoking remote method 'desktop-backend': Error: "invalid daemon settings: \"insecure-registries\":\n Must be host[:port] or CIDR"
```

Output of `docker info` on the Mac:

```
Client:
 Context:    default
 Debug Mode: false
 Plugins:
  buildx: Build with BuildKit (Docker Inc., v0.6.1-docker)
  compose: Docker Compose (Docker Inc., v2.0.0-rc.2)
  scan: Docker Scan (Docker Inc., v0.8.0)

Server:
 Containers: 4
  Running: 0
  Paused: 0
  Stopped: 4
 Images: 23
 Server Version: 20.10.8
 Storage Driver: overlay2
  Backing Filesystem: extfs
  Supports d_type: true
  Native Overlay Diff: true
  userxattr: false
 Logging Driver: json-file
 Cgroup Driver: cgroupfs
 Cgroup Version: 1
 Plugins:
  Volume: local
  Network: bridge host ipvlan macvlan null overlay
  Log: awslogs fluentd gcplogs gelf journald json-file local logentries splunk syslog
 Swarm: inactive
 Runtimes: io.containerd.runc.v2 io.containerd.runtime.v1.linux runc
 Default Runtime: runc
 Init Binary: docker-init
 containerd version: e25210fe30a0a703442421b0f60afac609f950a3
 runc version: v1.0.1-0-g4144b63
 init version: de40ad0
 Security Options:
  seccomp
   Profile: default
 Kernel Version: 5.10.47-linuxkit
 Operating System: Docker Desktop
 OSType: linux
 Architecture: x86_64
 CPUs: 2
 Total Memory: 1.94GiB
 Name: docker-desktop
 ID: K4NV:OOUS:LNWC:BE2D:W75R:I3AH:CD5B:OFIJ:QFGT:57TT:SXEY:JP3C
 Docker Root Dir: /var/lib/docker
 Debug Mode: true
  File Descriptors: 43
  Goroutines: 45
  System Time: 2021-09-16T13:31:24.174487976Z
  EventsListeners: 4
 HTTP Proxy: http.docker.internal:3128
 HTTPS Proxy: http.docker.internal:3128
 Registry: https://index.docker.io/v1/
 Labels:
 Experimental: true
 Insecure Registries:
  images:5000
  127.0.0.0/8
 Live Restore Enabled: false
```

daemon.json

```
{
  "builder" : {
    "gc" : {
      "defaultKeepStorage" : "20GB",
      "enabled" : true
    }
  },
  "features" : {
    "buildkit" : true
  },
  "insecure-registries" : [
    "<dns-name>:<port>"
  ],
  "registry-mirrors" : [

  ],
  "experimental" : true,
  "debug" : true
}
```

Dockerfile

```
FROM <dns-name>:<port>/java-base:latest

ADD sedexclient /opt/sedexclient

ENV SCS_USER scs

RUN useradd -M -g nogroup $SCS_USER

RUN chown -R $SCS_USER: /opt/sedexclient

RUN cp /opt/sedexclient/jce/oracle_java8/* $JAVA_HOME/jre/lib/security/

EXPOSE 8000

CMD ["/opt/sedexclient/bin/sedex-client-start.sh"]
```

Comment: @BMitch I edited the question. The solution in the other question does not work for me. The settings provided by the accepted answer don't seem to be valid in my case.

Comment: can you include your current daemon.json file and Dockerfile? Feel free to change hostnames to example.com for anything internal.

Comment: Hi @BMitch, sorry for the late answer. I included both of the files. I only replaced the name and port of our registry by <dns-name> and <port> respectively.

Comment: And to verify, you attempted to set `"insecure-registries": [ "<dns-name>:<port>", "http://<dns-name>:<port>" ],` and docker desktop threw an error message blocking you?

Comment: Yes, exactly. It threw the error I added to the question. But I only tried this on the Mac.